# JavaScript destructure object into other object set default value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, destructuring

I am destructuring the value of an object from an array. If array is empty, error happens. How to make default value, if array is empty?

Error happens if array, which I am destructuring is empty:

> "TypeError","message":"Cannot destructure property `payments` of 'undefined' or 'null'."

Code of destructuring (`await (...).toArray()` is returning array `[ { payments: @integer } ]`):

```
    ({
        [0]: { payments: users.finances.payments = 0 },
    } = await (
        await payments_collection.aggregate([
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    payments: { $sum: '$coins' },
                },
            },
        ])
    ).toArray());
```

Comment: Try replacing `{ [0]: { payments: users.finances.payments = 0 },  }` with `[{ payments: users.finances.payments = 0 } = {}]`

Answer (score 0):

@adiga, thanks for your answer.

I replaced `{ [0]: { payments: users.finances.payments = 0 } }` with `[{ payments: users.finances.payments = 0 } = {}]`

New working code:

```
    [{ payments: users.finances.payments = 0 } = {}] = await (
        await payments_collection.aggregate([
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    payments: { $sum: '$coins' },
                },
            },
        ])
    ).toArray();
```